# Unable to compile Java program from CMD

Tags: java

i have made a file youtube.java in C:\test> but I'm to compile using cmd

I have set the path in environmental variables

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin
```

I have code all the coding as given below

```
class apples{
     public static void main(string args[]){
      system.out.println("hello youtube!");
     }
}
```

but when I go for compile in cmd error comes as give below

```
youtube.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
 public static void main(string args[]){
                         ^
  symbol:   class string
  location: class apples
youtube.java:3: error: package system does not exist
  system.out.println("hello youtube!");
        ^
2 errors
```

PLease help me getting out of this

Comment: it's System not system. big and small letters are a important in programming

Comment: Use an IDE until you understand how to write Java and compile manually.

Comment: Hint: Java is case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Java is a case sensitive language, and there is not string class...

```
public static void main(string args[]){
```

String is the class you need to use..

the same criteria applies for

```
system.out.println("hello youtube!");
```

it must be

```
System.out.println("hello youtube!");
```

Comment: And the filename should be `apples.java` or the class name changed to `youtube`

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use class name as `apples.java` when you compile in cmd.
2. Please use keywords as they are accepted.

   Capitalize the first char `s` for -

   A. '[String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)' in line

   `public static void main(String args[])`

   B. '[System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)' in line

   `System.out.println("Your text here");`

Answer (score 0):

That is because of error in your method declaration . Correct main method declaration is public static void main(String[]args) . string is not a class in Java . Kindly try to explore things on your behalf before posting a question.